# Searchguard could not be Initialized with error: Root cause: MasterNotDiscoveredException[null]

Tags: elasticsearch, search-guard

I use k8s to deploy Elasticsearch.
Dockerfile:

```
FROM docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:6.3.1

USER elasticsearch

RUN elasticsearch-plugin install --batch analysis-kuromoji
RUN elasticsearch-plugin install --batch org.codelibs:elasticsearch-analysis-kuromoji-neologd:6.3.1
RUN elasticsearch-plugin install --batch com.floragunn:search-guard-6:6.3.1-22.3

RUN mkdir -p /usr/share/elasticsearch/batch/scripts
RUN mkdir -p /usr/share/elasticsearch/batch/logs

COPY searchguard_not_initialized_check_batch.sh /usr/share/elasticsearch/batch/scripts/

RUN rm -f /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml && rm -f /usr/share/elasticsearch/plugins/search-guard-6/sgconfig/* && mkdir -p /usr/share/elasticsearch/data
```

File searchguard_not_initialized_check_batch.sh to run

```
    sh /usr/share/elasticsearch/plugins/search-guard-6/tools/sgadmin.sh -diagnose -cd /usr/share/elasticsearch/plugins/search-guard-6/sgconfig -cn pnt-es.stg -key /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/cert/kirk-key.pem -cert /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/cert/kirk.pem -cacert /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/cert/root-ca.pem -nhnv
```

Elasticsearch.yml:

```
cluster.name: "pnt-es.stg"

discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: elasticsearch-service
discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes: {{ elasticsearch_log_minimum_master_nodes }}

network.host: ['_site_', '_local_']

node.name: ${HOSTNAME}

http.port: 9200
transport.tcp.port: 9300

path.data: /usr/share/elasticsearch/data
path.logs: /var/log/elasticsearch

searchguard.ssl.transport.pemcert_filepath: cert/esnode.pem
searchguard.ssl.transport.pemkey_filepath: cert/esnode-key.pem
searchguard.ssl.transport.pemtrustedcas_filepath: cert/root-ca.pem
searchguard.ssl.transport.enforce_hostname_verification: false
searchguard.ssl.http.enabled: true
searchguard.ssl.http.pemcert_filepath: cert/esnode.pem
searchguard.ssl.http.pemkey_filepath: cert/esnode-key.pem
searchguard.ssl.http.pemtrustedcas_filepath: cert/root-ca.pem
searchguard.allow_unsafe_democertificates: true
searchguard.allow_default_init_sgindex: true
searchguard.enterprise_modules_enabled: false
searchguard.authcz.admin_dn:
  - CN=kirk,OU=client,O=client,L=test,C=de
xpack.security.enabled: false
```

Error as below:
How can I fix it?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fMiQF.png)

Answer (score 0):

When I run this command, Error as below.

```
[elasticsearch@elasticsearch-daemonset-4qwcj ~]$ sh /usr/share/elasticsearch/plugins/search-guard-6/tools/sgadmin.sh --diagnos -cd /usr/share/elasticsearch/plugins/search-guard-6/sgconfig -cn pnt-es.stg -key /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/cert/kirk-key.pem -cert /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/cert/kirk.pem  -cacert /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/cert/root-ca.pem -nhnv
Search Guard Admin v6
Will connect to localhost:9300 ... done
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by io.netty.util.internal.ReflectionUtil (file:/usr/share/elasticsearch/plugins/search-guard-6/netty-common-4.1.16.Final.jar) to constructor java.nio.DirectByteBuffer(long,int)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of io.netty.util.internal.ReflectionUtil
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
Elasticsearch Version: 6.3.1
Search Guard Version: 6.3.1-22.3
Connected as CN=kirk,OU=client,O=client,L=test,C=de
Diagnostic trace written to: /usr/share/elasticsearch/sgadmin_diag_trace_2019-Oct-03_05-35-51.txt
Contacting elasticsearch cluster 'pnt-es.stg' and wait for YELLOW clusterstate ...
vi /usr/share/elasticsearch/sgadmin_diag_trace_2019-Oct-03_05-35-51.Cannot retrieve cluster state due to: null. This is not an error, will keep on trying ...
  Root cause: MasterNotDiscoveredException[null] (org.elasticsearch.discovery.MasterNotDiscoveredException/org.elasticsearch.discovery.MasterNotDiscoveredException)
   * Try running sgadmin.sh with -icl (but no -cl) and -nhnv (If that works you need to check your clustername as well as hostnames in your TLS certificates)
   * Make sure that your keystore or PEM certificate is a client certificate (not a node certificate) and configured properly in elasticsearch.yml
   * If this is not working, try running sgadmin.sh with --diagnose and see diagnose trace log file)
   * Add --accept-red-cluster to allow sgadmin to operate on a red cluster.
Cannot retrieve cluster state due to: null. This is not an error, will keep on trying ...
  Root cause: MasterNotDiscoveredException[null] (org.elasticsearch.discovery.MasterNotDiscoveredException/org.elasticsearch.discovery.MasterNotDiscoveredException)
   * Try running sgadmin.sh with -icl (but no -cl) and -nhnv (If that works you need to check your clustername as well as hostnames in your TLS certificates)
   * Make sure that your keystore or PEM certificate is a client certificate (not a node certificate) and configured properly in elasticsearch.yml
   * If this is not working, try running sgadmin.sh with --diagnose and see diagnose trace log file)
   * Add --accept-red-cluster to allow sgadmin to operate on a red cluster.
Cannot retrieve cluster state due to: null. This is not an error, will keep on trying ...
  Root cause: MasterNotDiscoveredException[null] (org.elasticsearch.discovery.MasterNotDiscoveredException/org.elasticsearch.discovery.MasterNotDiscoveredException)
   * Try running sgadmin.sh with -icl (but no -cl) and -nhnv (If that works you need to check your clustername as well as hostnames in your TLS certificates)
   * Make sure that your keystore or PEM certificate is a client certificate (not a node certificate) and configured properly in elasticsearch.yml
   * If this is not working, try running sgadmin.sh with --diagnose and see diagnose trace log file)
   * Add --accept-red-cluster to allow sgadmin to operate on a red cluster.
```